# Getting ConTeXt' \documentvariable into LuaTex

Tags: luatex, context-lmtx

I've been trying my luck getting into LuaTeX with ConTeXt.

I have a document that has some custom variables in its [`\startdocument`](https://wiki.contextgarden.net/Command/startdocument) variables (the ones you get with [`\documentvariable`](https://wiki.contextgarden.net/Command/documentvariable)). Say something like `\startdocument[myvar=15]`.

Of course I can get it to be typeset via LuaTeX with `context.documentvariable('myvar')`, but I can't use it to be manipulated with Lua - say, like in this example, getting this number from `[myvar]` to be added with a numeric value from Lua:

```
\startluacode
userdata['test'] = {}
ut = userdata.test

function ut.add(addto)
    local number = context.documentvariable('myvar') -- This throws an "attempt to perform arithmetic on a nil value (local 'number')" error
    local number = tokens.getters.macro(tokens.getters.macro('??documentvariables') .. 'myvar') -- and this throws an "attempt to concatenate a nil value" error
    local number = tokens.getters.macro(tokens.getters.macro('??documentvariable') .. 'myvar') -- same thing
    context(number + addto)
end
\stopluacode

\startdocument[myvar=15]
\ctxlua{userdata.test.add(20)}
\stopdocument
```

So as you see I tried some gibberish trying to follow the convention about [CLD passing variables](https://wiki.contextgarden.net/CLD_passing_variables#From_TeX_to_Lua) but can't get it to work - not sure if `\documentvariable` things have a special LuaTeX namespace or something like that so I can hook into it and get those variables to work with Lua.

###### Edit 1

Doing `local number = tonumber(context.documentvariable('myvar'))` won't work. Also it feels a little bit dirty

###### Edit 2

I've found that [there's a namespace for "documentdata"](https://wiki.contextgarden.net/Programming_in_LuaTeX#Namespaces). Digging a bit into the source code with my noob ass I found something that looks like a clue to me in mult-ini.lmt:

```
if documentdata then

    local prefix, getmacro

    function documentdata.variable(name)
        if not prefix then
            prefix = usednamespaces.variables .. ">document:"
        end
        if not getmacro then
            getmacro = tokens.getters.macro
        end
        return getmacro(prefix..name)
    end

end
```

So I supposed that one could use that `documentdata.variable()` function to get a variable from the document namespace, but when setting `local rate` with that, it also fails with "attempt to perform arithmetic on a nil value (local 'number')" - `documentdata.variable('number')` prints "nil".

Answer (score 0):

There's no clean solution that I'm aware of.

One option is to directly access the TeX macro that stores the variable's contents:

```tex
\setuppagenumbering[state=stop]
\setuppapersize[A10, landscape]

\startluacode
    function userdata.getvariable(namespace, name)
        local namespace = tokens.getters.macro("??" .. namespace)
        local value = tokens.getters.macro(namespace .. ":" .. name)
        return value
    end
\stopluacode

\startdocument[
    title={Test Title},
    author={First Last},
    number={12},
]

\cldcontext{userdata.getvariable("document", "title")}

\cldcontext{userdata.getvariable("document", "author"):upper()}

\cldcontext{tonumber(userdata.getvariable("document", "number")) ^ 3}

\stopdocument
```

As a more general (but less robust) option, you can use `publications.prerollcmdstring` to get the typeset result of an arbitrary macro (without actually typesetting it to the page):

```tex
\setuppagenumbering[state=stop]
\setuppapersize[A10, landscape]

\startluacode
    function userdata.documentvariable(name)
        return publications.prerollcmdstring(
            string.format("\\documentvariable{%s}", name)
        )
    end
\stopluacode

\startdocument[
    title={Test Title},
    author={First Last},
    number={12},
]

\cldcontext{userdata.documentvariable("title")}

\cldcontext{userdata.documentvariable("author"):upper()}

\cldcontext{tonumber(userdata.documentvariable("number")) ^ 3}

\stopdocument
```

Both options give the same output:

[image: output]

Answer (score 0):

After reading about [how to make `\command{arg1}{arg2}` hook into Lua*](https://wiki.contextgarden.net/Programming_in_LuaTeX#Making_%5Ccommand%7Barg1%7D%7Barg2%7D_hook_into_Lua) (and being really confused about [CLD passing variables](https://wiki.contextgarden.net/CLD_passing_variables#From_TeX_to_Lua)) I figured out that I can create a new variable in the userdata namespace where I can assign the value of `\documentvariable[myvar]`:

```
\def\setaddto#1{\ctxlua{userdata.test.addto = [==[#1]==]}}
```

Then it's gonna be just about how to call this bit before doing anything, which I did with `\setupdocument`:

```
\setupdocument[before={\setaddto{\documentvariable{myvar}}}]
```

That way, the whole thing looks like this, and seems to work with the totally-non-scientific tests I did - in this case, it prints 137:

```
\startluacode
userdata['test'] = {}
ut = userdata.test

function ut.add(number)
    context(number + ut.addto)
end
\stopluacode

\def\setaddto#1{\ctxlua{userdata.test.addto = [==[#1]==]}}
\setupdocument[before={\setaddto{\documentvariable{myvar}}}]

\startdocument[myvar=15]
\ctxlua{userdata.test.add(122)}
\stopdocument
```

###### * Addendum

Its title should be something like "Making \command{arg} hook into Lua"...